# How can I send a base64 encoded image?

Tags: botframework

I would like to respond to a conversation by providing a barcode (.PNG) that has been base64 encoded. Is that possible? Or is the only method of delivery thru a Url.

Comment: IMO, this is a better answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38252182

Comment: IMO, this is a better answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38252182

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
replyMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment()
{
     ContentUrl = $"data:image/jpeg;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(bdata)}"
});
```

Or as JSON:

```
{
    "attachments": 
    [
        {
            "contentUrl": $"data:image/jpeg;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(bdata)}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Where **bdata** is a byte array