# Display byte array as an image using botframework

Tags: botframework

I have a byte array from the uploaded pic by the user . I need to render this byte array as an image on **Skype** and other channels using **Bot-framework**

Answer (score 5):

Images can be sent as base64 encoded:

```
        byte[] imagedata = {your image}
        var image64 = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(imagedata);

        reply.Attachments.Add(new Attachment()
        {
            ContentUrl = image64,
            ContentType = "image/jpeg",
        });
```

Comment: This is working in Web App Bot, it's throws error in Microsoft teams...