# Send Image from byte[] using ms bot, Channel: Facebook, C#

Tags: c#, facebook, botframework, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I need to send image in bot.  converted my Image to Byte Array.

In emulator image is sending, but in Facebook, it is not sending.

Below is my code.

```
byte[] imageBytes12 = my image;
string url = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes12);

var attachmentsImage = new List<Attachment>();
var replyImage = MessageFactory.Attachment(attachmentsImage);
HeroCard menuCardImage = Cards.HeroImageCard(url);
replyImage.Attachments.Add(menuCardImage.ToAttachment());
await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(replyImage, cancellationToken);
```

I have seen

- [Send an image rather than a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39246174/send-an-image-rather-than-a-link)
- [Display byte array as an image using botframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38217811/display-byte-array-as-an-image-using-botframework/38252182)

when image is converted as byte, it is too lengthy to send as ContentUrl, thats why it is failing.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you already know that your image is too big to embed. So what's your question?

Comment: @ Kyle Delanley, how i can send that in facebook. Facebook is not accepting lengthy url .

Comment: Upload the file somewhere

Comment: hi @ Kyle Delanley, thanks for your response. i have saved the image in blob and giving reference to blob url. Thanks for your help appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using an image that's too large to embed as a data URL, you will need to provide a link to the image on a server